# How do I combine outputs in Simulink by changing a specific parameter?

Tags: control, control-system, feedback, matlab, simulink

I am studying a Cruise control system, and I want to change the coefficient of rolling friction and put them together in one graph keeping the remaining parameters the same. How do I store all the data in one graph?

Comment: Use a scope with a vector input

Comment: Could u please give me a link to where I could find it in detail, never used something like this in Simulink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the signals with a bus creator, then attach them to a scope. Each figure in the scope window can have 1 bus as an input. You can then export all the data to matlab (which will appear as a struct)

[image]
Source: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/buscreator.html

Comment: Thanks a ton man!